# Error in seq.int(r1$year, to$year, by) : 'from' must be a finite number

Tags: r

This is my code -

```
uc_ts_plot <- ggplot(monthly_sales, aes(DATE,DAUTONSA)) + geom_line(na.rm=TRUE) + 
+     xlab("Month") + ylab("Auto Sales in Thousands") + 
+     scale_x_date(labels = date_format(format= "%b-%Y"),breaks = date_breaks("1 year")) + 
+     stat_smooth(colour = "green")

uc_ts_plot
```

Error -

`geom_smooth() using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
    Error in seq.int(r1$year, to$year, by) : 'from' must be a finite number
    In addition: Warning message:
    Removed 627 rows containing non-finite values (stat_smooth).`

Any help? I was referring to this link - https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/343096_90b218e393454f79a5012e7ad0913e76.html but the code here isn't working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages(https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO tour (https://stackoverflow.com/tour), 
read about how to ask good questions (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this question checklist (https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). 
Lastly please learn how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What went wrong is the conversion of the DATE column to a Date format.

The example on the provided link suggests:

```
monthly_sales$DATE <- as.Date(monthly_sales$DATE, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Whereas the format of the cells are "1967-01-01".

Therefore, all dates are converted to NA.

The correct of handling this would be:

```
monthly_sales <- read.csv("DAUTONSA.csv",header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
monthly_sales$DATE <- as.Date(monthly_sales$DATE, "%Y-%m-%d")

uc_ts_plot <- ggplot(monthly_sales, aes(DATE,DAUTONSA)) + geom_line(na.rm=TRUE) + 
  xlab("Month") + ylab("Auto Sales in Thousands") + 
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format(format= "%b-%Y"),breaks = date_breaks("1 year")) + 
  stat_smooth(colour = "green")
```

Notice the change in the

```
monthly_sales$DATE <- as.Date(monthly_sales$DATE, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

line